# Why does hasPermission require both name and primKey?

Tags: permissions, liferay, primary-key

Liferay's [hasPermission](http://cdn.docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/security/permission/PermissionChecker.html#hasPermission%28long,%20java.lang.String,%20long,%20java.lang.String%29) method requires among others `name` and `primKey`:

```
boolean hasPermission(long groupId,
                      String name,
                      long primKey,
                      String actionId)
```

Here is the documentation for these two parameters:

```
name - the resource's name, which can be either a class name or a portlet ID
primKey - the primary key of the resource
```

Is it about the same resource?
If yes, why not just ask for `primKey`?

Comment: Different type of resource can have same primKey. For example: webcontent can have primkey 12345 , the same may be primkey of other resource(custom or liferays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Pankaj Kathiriya's comment (primKey is not a UUID, so there might be many objects to have the same primary key - it's just a `long` typically. Note that permission checks are done on `Resource` entities - their primary key is composed of the name (`String`) and the primKey (typically `long`)

This could also be used (not sure if it's actually done) to have a sanity check for the action name: The implementation could check if the given object class declares the action at all, and flag implementation bugs if not.